# Mimic iOS 7's Home Screen Search Bar on my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uisearchbar

I want to implement a search bar in my app which mimics the one on iOS 7's home screen. When I pull down, I want it to bounce down while having enough room on top for the status bar, and I want my current view to move down to make room for the search bar as well. How should I go about with this?

My current thought is to make a new UIView class, add a UISearchBar to it and add that view to my current view (So that I can scroll down to display the search bar). But is there a better way to do this?

This is how it looks like on the iPhone home screen
http://static.trustedreviews.com/94/000028d08/1a0e/Spotlight-Search.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you could create a UIView with a search bar in it. Add it to your main view and set your searchView origin.y to be less than 0 so it will hide below the top of the screen.
Next you could use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to track the dragging of your finger and update the origin.y of your searchView while you drag..